# 404 Error on Network Tab in production server ( Code 200 in local ). Using React js for front end

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, http-status-code-404, package.json

I am working with **React.js** on front-end.
The Code is running in a perfect flow no errors are shown while working with the flow.

But NETWORK Tab shows 404 error for the page in production mode. 
But its working fine on local server with code 200 in network tab.

This is affecting the optimization of the website and **google Ads are not running** because of persisting 404 error on pages.

**Note** : The error is showing on all pages except for the home page.

Screenshots of Network tabs for  production & local are below respectively.

[Production Mode Network Tab Showing 404 for Moratorium]
[image]

[Local Server Network Tab Showing 200 for Moratorium]
[image]

Console shows this error 
[screenshot of Console on Browser]
[image]

When Click on the file having 404 error
it shows me the code from index.html of my react app with a red cross in front of <!Doctype html> 
saying

> Failed to Load Resources
>
> [Console Log Screenshot]
> [image]

[Console log screenshot showing index.html file with 404 error]
[image]

scripts in package.json

```
{
 "scripts": {
   "start": "react-scripts start",
   "build": "react-scripts build",
   "test": "react-scripts test",
   "eject": "react-scripts eject",
   "scss": "node-sass --include-path ./src --include-path ./node_modules src/ -o src/",
   "sitemap": "babel-node src/sitemap/generator.js"
 },
 "eslintConfig": {
   "extends": "react-app"
 },
 "browserslist": {
   "production": [
     ">0.2%",
     "not dead",
     "not op_mini all"
   ],
   "development": [
     "last 1 chrome version",
     "last 1 firefox version",
     "last 1 safari version"
   ]
 },
 "devDependencies": {
   "babel-register": "^6.26.0",
   "redux-devtools": "^3.5.0"
 }
}
```

Comment: I hope you have tried production mode on your local.

Comment: Yes, I did. No errors on production mode on my local.

Comment: But still there is the same error on the production server on the web

Comment: Have you found any answer for this

Comment: @Pranavjeet.Mishra Unfortunately, No.

Comment: I am also facing the same issue. but not able to find any solution for this.